# Meaning of “take a knee”

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, metaphors, rhetorical-devices

Ice Cube's [intro](https://genius.com/Ice-cube-super-og-intro-lyrics) in his newest album starts with

> Yeah, you know me. Super OG.
>   Always down to take a knee.

What does this last sentence mean? He won‘t literally take someone’s knee I guess..

Comment: If you follow American football, this is an easy question, so I'll leave it to an American English speaker. Interestingly there are two possible interpretations.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Haha, unfortunately I don't watch American Football :D where I live, Handball is something like the "national sport".

Comment: But you could google the phrase "take a knee". Just as I did for OG (never heard of it before)

Comment: I immediately interpreted *take a knee* to refer to bowing to royalty (or, metaphorically, acquiescing to and respecting authority), which is probably how it would be interpreted to those in the UK (or anywhere that has a monarchy), and how it might have been in interpreted in the US prior to the whole football issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Semantically

The meaning of "take a knee" is very similar to ["take a seat"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-a-seat).

> *phrase*
>   *formal*
>
> If you take a seat, you sit down.
>
> - *'Take a seat,' he said in a bored tone.*
> - *Rachel smiled at him as they took their seats on opposite sides of the table.*

The difference between "take a seat" and "take a knee" is that with the latter, you kneel instead of sit.

---

### Contextually

The lyrics are not just focusing on the semantical meaning. They are in reference to [a recent form of activism centered around NFL player Colin Kaepernick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Kaepernick#Activism), who chose to kneel for the American anthem (when it is customary and expected to stand up) as a way of peacefully protesting because America is (quote Kaepernick) "a country that oppresses black people and people of color".

This sparked a wave of people taking a knee in support of both Kaepernick (who received backlash for his activism) and Kaepernick's cause.

Contextually, "taking a knee" can thus mean "show your support". Your quoted lyrics can be translated as

> Yeah, you know me. Super OG.
>   Always willing to show my support for causes I believe in even if it causes me to receive backlash.

But this translation doesn't quite flow enough to be used for the actual lyrics.

Comment: Okay top, this makes now sense to me..

Answer (score -1):

The expression will probably currently be perceived as referencing an American footballer, Colin Kaepernick, who knelt down on one knee instead of standing for the national anthem, as a protest against the current state of affairs in the US.

Comment: Very vague, not particularly helpful, better as a comment. And the peaceful protest was specific, and not necessarily anti-government.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Kaepernick#Activism

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Fully agree on the rest of your comment, but the peaceful protest was anti-government as Kaepernick himself elaborated on this. Quoting Kaepernick from the link you added: _"I am not going to stand up to show pride in a flag for a country that oppresses black people and people of color"_. It's not anti-government in the general anarchist anti-government sense (but you implied that, the answer didn't), but it is definitely anti-current-state-of-affairs.

Comment: Anti-current state of the affairs is too generic, it could have meant anything.